# An automorphism conjugate to its inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, automorphism-group

Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra, $k$ a field of characteristic zero.
Let $g$ be a $k$-algebra automorphism of $A$, and let $g^{-1}$ be its inverse.

Assume that $g^{-1}=u^{-1}gu$, for some automorphism (or anti-automorphism) $u$.

> Is being conjugate implies something 'interesting' about $g$ and $g^{-1}$?

I am not sure what 'interesting' exactly means; for example, $g$ and $g^{-1}$ have the same order (this is the only interesting thing I have succeeded to say thus far).

Does it matter if $A$ is commutative or not?

**A special case:**
Actually, I have a non-commutative algebra $A$ in mind, the first Weyl algebra $A_1$ (over $\mathbb{C}$, for example):

Denote the group of automorphisms of $A_1$ by $G$, and the group of automorphisms and anti-automorphisms of $A_1$ by $H$.
Let $\beta: (x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$.
Then $H=G \cup G\beta$.
Let $f$ be an involution on $A_1$ (= an anti-automorphism of order two).
$f=g\beta$, for some automorphism $g$, and $f^2=1$ means
$g \beta g \beta =1$, so $g^{-1}= \beta g \beta$ ($u=\beta$).
I wonder if the order of $g$ in this case must be finite (probably not?).

Thank you very much!

Comment: $g$ and $g^{-1}$ should always have the same order in any group.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, so my additional information that they are conjugate is not needed to conclude that they have the same order. Any suggestions for 'interesting'? Any ideas about my special case?

Comment: If $g$ commutes with $\beta$, then $g$ is of order two (= $g$ is an anti-involution). But what if we do not know that $g$ commutes with $\beta$?

Comment: I guess I should work as follows: (1) Take $g$ affine, calculate $\beta g \beta$, compare it to $g^{-1}$ and find out what is $g$ (2) Same as in (1) with $g$ triangular. (3)  the general case is a finite product of affines and triangulars $g= g_1,\ldots,g_m$. $g^{-1}=\beta g \beta= \beta g_1 \cdots g_m \beta= \beta g_1 \beta \beta g_2 \beta \cdots \beta g_m \beta$.

Comment: For example, if $g: (x,y) \mapsto (ax+by,cx+dy)$ with $ad-bc=1$, then a direct calculation shows that $a=d$; just compare $g^{-1}: (x,y) \mapsto (dx-by,-cx+ay)$ to $\beta g \beta: (x,y) \mapsto (ax-by,-cx+dy)$. Generally, it seems that such $g$ need not be of finite order.